# Flutter web: Webview with payment gateway not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have created a flutter web app running in chrome, in which I have used [webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webviewx) for calling the payment gateway(which we have set in the backend server).

- In that URL after entering card details we redirect it to [moyasar url](https://api.moyasar.com/) at that time it throws an error as follows:-

> Refused to display 'https://api.moyasar.com/' in a frame because it
> set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are displaying the URL in an iframe. Make sure you are displaying the URL directly on the web view component.

Comment: Thank you @Ali for your answer, Yeah actually web developer has created one page to fill in the information about card details and then it will be redirected to the `https://api.moyasar.com/` URL with the POST request. While displaying that URL I am getting this issue.

Comment: If possible, can we have a call to discuss further?

Comment: There is no need for a call, the problem happens when you try to display the previous URL inside an <iframe>. Please don't use it and ask your backend developer not to use an <iframe>.

Comment: Actually, I removed the backend part from this process and developed one page from my side in Flutter Web where I can take the card details and pass them to the Moyasar. Moyasar gave me one URL for the transaction. That URL is also not working If I open it with WebView. I think WebView will not allow to use that. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please send all the details to developers@moyasar.com